# Retrieving Salesforce Objects with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sales-cloud

I need to show a content area if there is more than one row in a specific table, and other content area if there is only one row in this table.

It’s not possible to consult Synchronized Data Extensions from Salesforce using AMPscript, and I can’t use the Journey Builder Data Extension because I need to see the current data value about the subscribers, and the Journey DE only provides the initial data value  of subscribers.

I’m trying to use lookup rows with Retrieve Salesforce Objects using it as a table to do a rowcount with its result.

I validate the email in Content Builder and it doesn’t show any problem, but when I activate the Journey, my contacts don’t recieve the email.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to resolve this?
I’m using the code below:

---

Like Adam said I had unnecessary lookuprows, only post this because I need to add the ID filter in the retrivesalesforceobjects

```
%%[

set @nomejob = AttributeValue("Questionario__c:Nome_Job_simplificado__c")
set @id = AttributeValue("Questionario__c:Pesquisador__c")
set @rs = retrievesalesforceobjects('Questionario__c','Pesquisador__c,Status_anterior_do_questionario__c,Status_do_Questionario__c','Status_anterior_do_questionario__c','=','Em Treinamento','Status_do_Questionario__c','=','Expirado','Pesquisador__c',`=`,@id)

set @rowcount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowcount > 1 then 

]%%

CONTENT 1

%%[ else ]%%

CONTENT 2

%%[endif]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do an additional `lookupRows()` in your `rowCount()` function.

```
%%[

set @nomejob = AttributeValue("Questionario__c:Nome_Job_simplificado__c")
set @id = AttributeValue("Questionario__c:Pesquisador__c")
set @rs = retrievesalesforceobjects('Questionario__c','Pesquisador__c,Status_anterior_do_questionario__c,Status_do_Questionario__c','Status_anterior_do_questionario__c','=','Em Treinamento','Status_do_Questionario__c','=','Expirado')

set @rowcount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowcount > 1 then 

]%%

CONTENT 1

%%[ else ]%%

CONTENT 2

%%[endif]%%
```